# Solve a function consist of two functions in a sigma summation

Tags: measure-theory, convolution, cauchy-sequences

I'm still new in here. I have been struggling to solve an equation. The equation is like:

f(T)= $\sum_{i=0}^t [g(T-i)*d(i)]$

It is an equation describing the relationship between f(T), g(T) and d(t). I'm trying to form an equation for g(T), in terms of f(T) and d(t). I tried to convert the sigma notation into integral so that I could differentiate both sides. However, I think it is impossible as both of them are different functions and they are not constant value. Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: What is the form of $g(x)$ ?

Comment: It can be any form. This equation is formed through a theory. Does it necessary to provide the exact equation for each of the function?

Comment: If it can be of any form, it will be difficult to go beyond the equation you wrote. If $g(x)$ is a polynomial, $f(T)$ is a polynomial too. Think about Fourier development. If you need to solve, say, $f(T)=C$, may be only numerical methods would be the way to go. This is whay I was asking the question.

Comment: All these three equations are potentially to be polynomial. It is impossible to assume f(T) =C. Anyway, I will look into Fourier series.

Comment: You wrote that you are *struggling to solve an equation*

Comment: Yea. So looking for people who can give me some hints or even solution.

Comment: I still can't solve it.=(

Comment: Assuming your $t$ and $T$ are the same, your identity is the same as the generating function identity $$\sum_{T=0}^\infty f(T) x^T = \bigg( \sum_{T=0}^\infty g(T) x^T \bigg) \bigg( \sum_{T=0}^\infty d(T) x^T \bigg).$$ Therefore you can find the generating function for $d$ by dividing the generating functions for $f$ and $g$; once you have the generating function, you can try to recover the coefficients $d(T)$ from it.

Comment: Sorry, I just found out I was actually wanted to get g(T) instead of d(t). And, what will the x^T be?